# Create table with few rows with migration in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5.3

I would like to create a table that will save the data for only 10 rows. How can I do it via `migration` in Laravel 5.3?

Comment: Can you please give us more info about what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want a table that saves only 10 rows of data?

Comment: yes, i want  to create table that holds 10 rows of data only

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please make sure that you try on your own first. Post the code that you have tried, and say why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.3 provides `seeding`, also combined with `model factories`. I'm guessing you're using Eloquent models instead of query builder.

## Model Factory

Here an example from Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding#using-model-factories)

```
factory(App\User::class, 10)->create();
```

This code creates 10 fake users via the User Eloquent model. The declaration of a fake user could be done in `database/factories/ModelFactory.php`.

## Seeding

Again, a partial example from Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding#writing-seeders). You can call the model factory directly from the existing DatabaseSeeder (no need to create a new seeder).

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 10)->create();    
    }
}
```

## Run

- `php artisan db:seed` to seed the data in existing table structure
- `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` for completely rebuilding your database and running the seeders

Full documentation and examples, see the provided links above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such restriction. You can create table as usual and just add 10 rows. If you're asking about hwo to add 10 rows to the table, read about [seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding).

Also, if you have just 10 simple rows, consider using [config file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration) for that. You can do something like this:

```
'my-data' => [
    1 => ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 30],
    2 => ['name' => 'Alan', 'age' => 40],
    ....
],
```

And access this data with `config('my-config.my-data')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dummy data to be filled into your table without any hassle you can take a use of **[Faker Package](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)** by [fzaninotto](https://github.com/fzaninotto).
The process would be like

Install faker via running below command in terminal (from project's root directory):

```
composer require fzaninotto/faker
```

Then in your `routes.php` you can push dummy entries like this:

```
// Just for an example I am using route to demonstrate the general use
Route::get('/customers',function(){
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    $limit = 10; // this value sets number of rows to be created

    // generate data by accessing properties
    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        User::create([ 
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'phoneNumber' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        ]);
    }
});
```

This would create total 10 rows  in your table with some dummy data.. Hope this helps